# css only centered nav with no set width

Tags: html, css

I was able to put together a centered nav (as you can see in the link below) but there is a **2-3 pixel offset** between each nav element. `Margin` and `Padding` are both set to `0`, but it's still there and I can't figure it out for the life of me...

Any ideas?

If not, I'll have to throw together some JS that will detect and set the width with a automatic margin to center it...

http://quspot.com/mb/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to remove all the `spaces/newlines` from between the `li` elements.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could try the letter-spacing fix:

http://jsfiddle.net/VQNp6/4/